# Save and load checkpoint pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, checkpointing

i make a model and save the configuration as:

```
def checkpoint(state, ep, filename='./Risultati/checkpoint.pth'):  
    if ep == (n_epoch-1):
        print('Saving state...')
        torch.save(state,filename)
checkpoint({'state_dict':rnn.state_dict()},ep)
```

and then i want load this configuration :

```
state_dict= torch.load('./Risultati/checkpoint.pth')
    rnn.state_dict(state_dict)
```

when i try, this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train.py", line 288, in <module>
rnn.state_dict(state_dict)
File "/home/marco/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 593, in state_dict
destination._metadata[prefix[:-1]] = dict(version=self._version)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_metadata'
```

where i do wrong?

thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load `rnn.state_dict()` stored in the *dictionary* you loaded:

```
rnn.load_state_dict(state_dict['state_dict'])
```

Look at [`load_state_dict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.load_state_dict) method for more information.